# Gson.toJson adding extra quotes to string value of JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

My JSON object is like: `{ids:[2079]}`, but when I'm trying to get String value using

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new GsonExclusionStrategy()).create();
 gson.toJson(body);
```

gson.toJson() is printing `"{\"ids\":[2079]}"`, where as the expected behaviour is `{\"ids\":[2079]}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are double calling toJson() method which is already a String.
I mean if you call toJson() on `"{ids:[2079]}"`, then it will produce `"{\"ids\":[2079]}"`. So check your object.

Comment: Thanks, I got my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I gone through same  problem but finally i got solution.
i added commons-lang3-3.4 JAVA Library.[download library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonslang3301jar.htm)

And used sample code.

```
String varibleString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(your JSON response string);
varibleString = varibleString .substring(1, varibleString .length() - 1);           
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(varibleString );
             }catch(Exception e)
              { 
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }
```

StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(your JSON response string);
this method will help you to remove unwanted character from JSON Strting.